# NIFI - unable to replicate null message(tombstones) between kafka topics using PublishKafka_2_6

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-nifi

I'm trying to replicate data between two Kafka topics that are defined with **cleanup policy - compact** using NIFI 1.21.0 ,The problem is that null messages(tombstones) replicate with a wrong value (not null ),I'm using  PublishKafka_2_6 to insert the data to the target topic.

for example message key 666 .

Source topic edi_test_compact .
[source topic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sNX8K.png)

target topic edi_test_compact2
[target topic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sq6SF.png)

nifi config

[nifi config1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vIMRt.png)
[nifi config2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e8hKt.png)

Comment: Maybe you've configured Nifi to produce lists of records in a flowfile, not single values, so that's why there are no nulls and hex encoding isn't the default partitioning strategy for Kafka. MirrorMaker2 is more commonly used to replicate Kafka topics, but the problem with mirroring compacted topics is that they won't immediately be similarly compacted.

Comment: Thanks , Where and how to configure a single record in nifi flowfile ?

Comment: There should be, but I don't frequently use Nifi to remember what it is... Is there a specific reason not to use MirrorMaker2 rather than Nifi for replicating a topic?

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think that in MirrorMaker2 you must have the same definitions (partition numbers ,etc) in the source and target topics.